# JDO for Google App Engine: escaping quotes

Tags: security, google-app-engine, jdo, jdoql

How do I escape parameters of queries in JDO (Google App Engine)?

For example, how do I make the next snippet safe, if the variable name may contain unsafe chars as single quotes (')

```
PersistenceManager pm = ...;
String query = "select from Person where name='"+name+"'";
List<Shortened> shortened = (List<Shortened>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

Comment: I have a bit of more code and references here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552064/appengine-datastore-query-escaping-single-quote/9552818#9552818

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use query parameters instead, it's a much safer than including the values in the query itself. Here is an example from the GAE documentation:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("select from Employee " +
                          "where lastName == lastNameParam " +
                          "order by hireDate desc " +
                          "parameters String lastNameParam");

List<Employee> results = (List<Employee>) query.execute("Smith");
```

Comment: +1 bazillion. I wish there was some way to make a computer explode if you try to use string substitution on a query.

Comment: Sadly, the GAE documentation examples use String query = "..." style, at least the pages I found do.

Having trouble finding where to import Query from, but I haven't looked much, yet; I'll get it!  :)

Comment: Btw, it's:
    import javax.jdo.Query;
For the next guy looking.  Duh.  ;)