# appengine datastore query escaping single quote (')

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine, jdo

I have used javax.jdo.Query like here [JDO for Google App Engine: escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496996/jdo-for-google-app-engine-escaping-quotes). Yet, my query string with single quote (') keep getting exploded.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + Book.class.getName() + " where mArtist== '"+ artist + "' &&  mTitle=='" + title + "'");
```

Here is the exception

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Portion of expression could not be parsed: 't Give Up' 
org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryCompilerSyntaxException: Portion of expression could not be parsed: 't Give Up'
```

Here is this query.toString()

```
SELECT FROM com.example.Book WHERE mArtist== 'Famous Writer' &&  mTitle=='We Won''t Give Up'
```

Yeh, I have even escaped the single quote(') with double single quote per appengine docs

[a str literal, as a single-quoted string. Single-quote characters in the string must be escaped as ''. For example: 'Joe''s Diner'](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "exploded"?  What exactly is happening?

Comment: sorry. getting a bit dramatic and forget the Exception triggered. I have updated the post with Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a query by string concatenation is almost always a risky thing to do, even when SQL Injection attacks aren't possible. (They aren't with GAE.)

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html#Introducing_Queries and note the bit on "parameter substitution".

Answer (score 1):

The example code in the document only cover a single parameter substitution. Here is a bit more.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Book.class);
query.setFilter("mArtist == artist && mTitle == title");
query.declareParameters("String artist,String title");              
List<Book> list = (List<Book>) query.execute("Famous Writer","We Won't Give Up");
```

Some SO questions worth reading :

[How to dynamically build JDO Queries on multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935762/how-to-dynamically-build-jdo-queries-on-multiple-parameters)

[Google Datastore problem with query on *User* type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933023/google-datastore-problem-with-query-on-user-type)